# Continue enumeration after a paragraph not belonging to the list

Tags: r-markdown

I am writing an examen using Markdown that at the end I print in pdf. It looks like this:

```
---
title: |
  | An exam
author: Me
output:
  pdf_document: default
  toc: yes
  html_document: null
subtitle: Some subtitle

---

Some paragraph introduces the question.

    a. Easy question

Another paragraph giving more context for a further question.

    a. Hard question.
```

My problem is that the Hard question restarts the counter in "a.". But it should be "b." I don't want the "Another paragraph..." to be within the "a." element. This "Another paragraph..." must be at the same level as the "Some paragraph introduces..." one.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the problem is. Just write `b.`? Notice, that I used one tab to indent thel ist item and a linebreak before and after them.

```
---
title: |
  | An exam
author: Me
output:
  pdf_document: default
  toc: yes
subtitle: Some subtitle
---

Some paragraph introduces the question.
  
  a. Easy question

Another paragraph giving more context for a further question.
  
  b. Hard question.
```

[image]